# Inheriting a class from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, module

Suppose I have backend.py file and inside is:

```
class Database():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def printDatabase(self):
        print('Printing test')
```

And suppose I have another fie called frontend.py

```
import backend

class Tester(backend.Database):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def testInheritance(self):
        self.printDatabase()
```

Is this the correct code to inherit a class from another file, and use one of its methods?

Comment: Yes; you may want to work through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: Its fine to inherit from another file, though you should call the parents constructor.

Comment: Did you try and see?